# Real time mark recognition on Android

Tags: android, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, zxing

I'm building an Android app that has to identify, in realtime, a mark/pattern which will be on the four corners of a visiting card. I'm using a preview stream of the rear camera of the phone as input.

I want to overlay a small circle on the screen where the mark is present. This is similar to how reference dots will be shown on screen by a QR reader at the corner points of the QR code preview.

I'm aware about how to get the frames from camera using native Android SDK, but I have no clue about the processing which needs to be done and optimization for real time detection. I tried messing around with OpenCV and there seems to be a bit of lag in its preview frames.

So I'm trying to write a native algorithm usint raw pixel values from the frame. Is this advisable? The mark/pattern will always be the same in my case. Please guide me with the  algorithm to use to find the pattern.

The below image shows my pattern along with some details (ratios) about the same (same as the one used in QR, but I'm having it at 4 corners  instead of 3)

I think one approach is to find black and white pixels in the ratio mentioned below to detect the mark and find coordinates of its center, but I have no idea how to code it in Android. I looking forward for an optimized approach for real-time recognition and display.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: just look for papers on QR codes or check out open source libraries that support QR reading. the markers look the same so you can apply the detectin algorithms to your markers.

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, maybe look at [this tutorial](http://aishack.in/tutorials/scanning-qr-codes-1)?.

Answer (score 0):

1. Detecting patterns on four corners of a visiting card:

   - Assuming background is white, you can simply try [this method](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/glyph_recognition/).
2. Needs to be done and optimization for real time detection:

   - Yes, you need OpenCV
   - [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIZ-tXJuC8s) is an example of real-time marker detection on Google Glass using OpenCV

     - In this example, image showing in tablet has delay (blutooth), Google Glass preview is much faster than that of tablet. But, still have lag.